# Laravel connection timed out

Tags: mysql, laravel, connection

I've searched a loot on google about this problem and I tried everything.
I have a database of a game from a hosting and I bought another webhost (shared hosting) from another company.

I have Laravel 7 on my website and I want to display all users informations from database and many other things.

The problem that i'm facing, is that, I need to access the database remote OUT (which I spoke with the support of the shared hosting and they said that they allow it), but still I get this error:

`[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out at /home/kirosne1/web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)`

The page is render (for example: login page) but when I click the 'login button' to check if the user exist, I wait for aboout 30 seconds and it gets me error 404 and in laravel.log is the above error.

My .env is something like this:
(example):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=195.205.39.83
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=hji2jsad232
DB_USERNAME=hji2jsad232
DB_PASSWORD=23sadsadsa
```

I tried to connect from a local mysql on the shared hosting i bought, and is working, but remote OUT is not.

I tried changing the php version from cpanel, also to clear the caches and it didn't work.

What should I do?

**EDIT:** The problem was because of my shared hosting, so I've changed the hosting provider and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Did you clear your config cache?

Comment: yes @MahdiJedari

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? Having an apparently similar issue,

Comment: Yes, I've changed the hosting provider @Nick

Answer (score 0):

You should manually change credentials of DB in bootstrap/cache/config.php
Looks like this:

```
'mysql' => 
  array (
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => NULL,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '3306'
        ),
```

Comment: Well i don't have that file in that location, but I've tried to edit on ``/config/database.php`` and still not working.